# Python Pandas: Ploting GPS track as it evolves in time

Tags: python, pandas, gps, time-series

I have a dataframe with latitude, longitude columns indexed by datetime. Time-series data represents a track of an object in time:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 137824 entries, 2015-03-01 07:16:39 to 2015-04-01 00:12:38
Data columns (total 5 columns):
accuracy     137824 non-null float64
longitude    137824 non-null float64
latitude     137824 non-null float64
```

How to plot from these points a track to see how it changes in time? I first create an ordered list of all the points in the dataframe with Shapely:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]

# Define EPSG4326 coordinate reference system for GPS latitude and longitude (CRS)
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

I can plot all the points then:

```
points.plot(color='green')
```

This plots all points in 2D space where x=latitude and y=longitude. How to plot these points ordered in time (in 3D)?

*** Update ***

Plotting with Geopandas is not my ultimate goal after all. I am looking for any approach that will allow to plot GPS coordinates in time. Maybe with regular Pandas plot method or seaborn plotting library. The idea is to visualize how moving object coordinates change with time, so to say to show history of its positions. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can look at this：https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/622

Comment: Thanks! Please see my question update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you need, but I think I can use the Matplotlib Library.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Time')
ax.plot(df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values, mdates.date2num(df2['dtime'].tolist()),label=str(1))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Explain:**

The role of `label` is to identify which category the current data belongs to, and I used ID as an example.

`mdates.date2num`is used in conjunction with `set_major_formatter`.
If we use the following code：

```
ax.plot(df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values, df2['dtime'].values,label=str(1))
```

As a result, the graph time axis is shown to be a large int：
[image]

If we only use the `set_major_formatter` to modify the time display format to get the wrong：

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

`mdates.date2num` converts time into smaller numbers,so we need to use `mdates.date2num` and `set_major_formatter`

Comment: Yes, I need something like this, thanks! This code works but displays only some fraction of my data along all three axes: x,y, and z. How can I resize the plot to show all data? I also get this warning: ".../usr/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:531: UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. ""

Comment: The warning lacks label. If there are more than one track, you can use it to label ID, and you can look at the updated code and the picture. I don't understand what it means to show all the data.

Comment: Do you mean that the time is not completely wrong? This is the mistake that I have corrected.

Comment: I get KeyError: 'taxi_id' What is ‘tax_id’? I don’t have such a column in my data.
Please, also explain the purpose of ‘mdates.date2num(df2['date'].tolist()),label=str(i)’. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I'm sorry, I used ID as example because I thought you had a lot of track, and I've updated the content.